# White screen apear on emulator IONIC5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I created the ionic 5 projects with angular CLI.

Now I am using an emulator for testing in android mobile.

I need a live reload project so using this command I run project.

`ionic Cordova run android -l` and `ionic Cordova run android -lcs`

but the only a white screen is there in the emulator for the emulator I am using android studio.

Comment: I faced the same problem and still facing, when using ionic cordova it gives a white screen on emulator but works fine on android device, but if you use ionic capacitor it will work on emulator, maybe its something related to cordova runtime at latest ionic updates (ionic 4+)

Comment: But I dont know to use in device if you know so write steps